# Azure Notification Hub Management SDK - Metrics Missing?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-notificationhub

We are trying to pull Azure Notification Hub Metrics using the C# Client Libraries, but it seems the namespace is missing from the `NotificationHubs` nuget package.

According to the Azure SDK for .NET docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.management?view=azure-dotnet), there should be a `Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.Management` namespace some where, but i have checked both the NotificationHubs client and Management SDK and its not there.

1) Where is this missing namespace? 2) How can i get Notification Hub Metrics programmatically using the C# SDK libraries?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the metrics for Notification Hubs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics#microsoftnotificationhubsnamespacesnotificationhubs). Use MonitorManagementClient under Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Fluent to retrieve the Metrics of any type of Azure resource.